# Can't click on this element on heroku

Tags: python, selenium, heroku

I have this robot that takes in some data and places an order in another website. everything worked fine locally, but on heroku the button place order doesn't get clicked for some reason. here is the code:

```
place_order = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'placeOrderBtn')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", place_order)
print('place order: ', place_order)
```

I have also tried `place_order.click()` but same result.
its also worth mentioning that on the print statment, so the selenium element gets printed.
here is also the arguments i use to run the robot on heroku

```
chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), options=chrome_options)
```

I have also tried `chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")` with `--` before stat_maximized.

and here is the HTML [image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to click any element using `JavaScript`, use the Selenium plugin API and tools:

In Selenium there is a class called `WebDriverWait`, you can use it for smart waiting until an element is clickable, visible, hidden and so on:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "placeOrderBtn")))
element.click()
```

You may change the timeout of 10 seconds, this will allow for a longer wait time. If the element is clickable before the timeout passed - the element will be clicked.

Comment: I have tried that too, didn't work. another thing why i use JS because i have noticed that some buttons when depolyed on heroku doesn't get clicked with `.click()`

Comment: @6rs Is the button sits inside of an Iframe element?

Comment: no it's a button inside a div

Comment: @6rs Please show us the HTML section with the button you are trying to click on, as text or image.

Comment: `<div class="delivery__column delivery__column--4 col-xs-12 col-md-12 end-md"><button id="placeOrderBtn" tabindex="11" type="submit" class="btn">place order</button><!----><!----></div>`

Comment: @6rs Update in the question please, show all the section. I want to make sure there is no Iframe wrapping your element

Comment: added the html as an img

Comment: mmm...try using element.focus() and then click on the element. If that does Not work, try action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(element).click().perform()